# Access denied. Apache / Devilbox for Windows

Tags: windows, веб-программирование, apache, docker

Есть проект в Devilbox, на Ubuntu все работало без каких-либо серьёзных проблем. Однако на windows при попытке зайти на localhost, где должна быть домашняя страница devilbox, приходит ошибка 403. В чём может быть дело? Думал, что Windows требует каких-либо дополнительных настроек для корректной работы Docker-контейнеров, однако, ничего по этому поводу не нашел. Ранее на Windows таким не занимался, поэтому могу ошибаться.

[image: CСкриншот из браузера]

При попытке открыть соответствующий адрес у WSL (в моем случае http://127.0.1.1:80) результат точно такой же. Может быть, дело в WSL, однако решений такой проблемы я найти не смог.

Comment: Что у вас забыл значок VPN возле адресной строки?

Comment: @andreymal ярлык встроенного ВПН браузера. На момент снятия скриншота выключен.